# Screen artifacts, not present on screenshots or video capture

Tags: video, display, gpu, external-display, visual-artifacts

This has been a problem that has been recurring for a while, but now I finally found a way to replicate it consistently (details on that below).

The thing is, there are flickering horizontal artifacts appearing on my screen. See gif below:

[image]

Such artifacts can be generally random: They can appear on any web page or even the desktop itself, though they seem to be more rare in full-screen applications, such as games. Funnily enough, I discovered that I'm getting them **consistently** on https://plato.stanford.edu/ (where the gif was recorded).

Now comes the **interesting part**:
These artifacts *do not appear on a screenshot or video capture*! I had to record the gif using my mobile phone.

This leads me to think it's not a GPU, driver, or other such issue; I suspect it has something to do with the monitor. I've tried tweaking the refresh rate and other monitor settings, with no change (i.e. the artifacts persist).

**Questions:**

1. Am I right to assume it's a monitor issue, as a GPU or other problem would also show on a screenshot/video capture?
2. Any idea on how to fix this?

If relevant, I'm using Windows 10 and this is a desktop computer with a Radeon R7 GPU. If any other info is required, let me know.

**Edit**: Troubleshooting, I noticed that changing the monitor's color temperature from *Warm* to *Cool* makes the problem disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it doesn't show on screenshots or video recordings, that only points to it being hardware as opposed to software, but not to precisely which component.

The type of noise shown in your gif doesn't look typical of GPU fail, so my first suspect would be either the display **or** the cable.

Simplest test would be to change the cable - to a different type if you have one - ie, if it's currently DVI, try a DisplayPort etc, rather than just another DVI. Spray the plugs & sockets with contact cleaner [with the power completely off & give it plenty of time to dry afterwards.]
Next simple test is to try the display on a different computer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll try them and report back when I have more info/results.

Comment: **New info** (added to question): Changing the monitor's color temperature from _Warm_ to _Cool_ makes the problem disappear. Any conclusions we can draw from that?

Comment: Not really:\ If it's just an OSD switch then that should be nothing more than a profile change.

Comment: I tried a different monitor and I can confirm it was a monitor issue.